# Передача данных из частичного представления в главное ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Код главного представления:

```
@model List<ViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.Action("_partial")
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
}
```

Код частичного:

```
@model List<ViewModel>
@foreach (ViewModel item in Model) 
{
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => item.Name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.Id)
    </div>
}
```

При сабмите модель в контроллер не отправляется. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте передать модель в частичное представление
@Html.RenderPartial("_partial", Model)

Comment: у меня частичное представление со своей логикой, по-этому используется @Html.Action()